# Cypher, Reusing information, with EXISTS{} as varname and then use varname, fails

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Query should create a Connection from A to B if this doesn't lead to a cycle. This means I can't connect A to B if there is already a connection from B to A.

I have following query:

```
1   MATCH (a:User) WHERE ID(a) = 0 
2   MATCH (b:User) WHERE ID(b) = 1
3   WITH a, b, NOT EXISTS{(b)-[*]->(a)} as A
4   WHERE A
5   MERGE (a)-[:has_connection]->(:Connection)-[:supports]->(b);
6   RETURN 
7   CASE A
8       WHEN TRUE THEN 'success'
9       ELSE 'error'
10  END
```

1, 2 -> I just find 2 nodes and name them a and b
3 -> I want to check if there is no connection from b to a and save the result in the variable A
4,5 -> if A is true I want to create a connection from a to b
6 - 10 -> I return a debug string by the condition A

I thought this syntax is correct but I am getting following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `A` not defined (line 2, column 10 (offset: 18))
"    CASE A"
          ^
```

I must have misunderstand scopes in Cypher.

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

I am expecting to get the result "success" if there was no connection from b to a and if there was a connection I want to get the result "error".

Answer (score 0):

Despite that the query is not optimal
the error is  simply the semicolon i put in in line 5

after removing it, i get the expected result.

I hope the snippet helps someone anyways, for optimization ideas please reply

Comment: Your code does not work the way you wanted. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even after you remove the erroneous semicolon in line 5, your query would not completely work the way you want. That is because when `A` is false the `WHERE A` clause would immediately end your query (and it would never return 'error').

This query will work as you intended:

```
MATCH (a:User), (b:User)
WHERE ID(a) = 0 AND ID(b) = 1
WITH a, b, NOT (b)-[*]->(a) as A
CALL {
  WITH *
  WITH * WHERE A
  MERGE (a)-[:has_connection]->(:Connection)-[:supports]->(b)
}
RETURN CASE A
  WHEN TRUE THEN 'success'
  ELSE 'error' END AS result
```

This query uses a [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) to avoid ending the query prematurely when `A` is false.

Comment: First of all thank you, 
I have a few questions:
1. You turned NOT EXISTS {(b)-[\*]->(a)} as A, to: NOT (b)-[\*]->(a) as A,  is it equivalent? In the doc was described that Exists returns true when the first path was found. So i thought it has to be more performant.

2. Why the Douplicate With * With * Where A,

Comment: 1. The syntax I used is equivalent to using `EXISTS`. 2. Read the documentation that I linked to for an explanation.